# All local variables show "Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument (...)" in a WinUI 3 project using VS 2022

Tags: c#, winui-3

After setting break points and trying to step through the values of variables in a WinUI 3 project, I'm getting the following:

> Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because it is
> not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has
> been optimized away.

I'm seeing this for basically every local variable. I've searched for hours attempting to fix this but to no avail.

I'm running the project in [Debug > x64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDz6T.png) as a packaged app. [Optimize code is turned off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akIWQ.png). [JIT optimizations are also off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqlxx.png). I'm using Windows 11 but it's also occurring on Windows 10. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 to debug. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it was a bug with the WinUI 3 Template Studio. This has since been resolved, but if you are using a project created before the fix was integrated you can take a look at the github issue I submitted for the fix:

https://github.com/microsoft/TemplateStudio/issues/4485#issuecomment-1142702263

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same thing. As a workaround I accepted that I can't debug when compiled natively, so I settled for a new 'Any CPU' platform assigned to the winui 3 app project itself. Then all debugging works again for me.

[image: Configuration Manager Example]

Note that this requires that you allow this in the project file, using the `AllowNeutralPackageWithAppHost`. Like this:

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
         :
         : snap
         :
        <AllowNeutralPackageWithAppHost>true</AllowNeutralPackageWithAppHost>
         :
    </PropertyGroup>
```